# Find the basis of set given by matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, complex-numbers, span

In linear space of matrix $2\times 3$ over $C$ we have subspace  generated by:  $ A= \{{\left[\begin{array}{ccc}i&i&i\\i&0&1\end{array}\right]}$ ${\left[\begin{array}{ccc}i&i&-i\\-i&-1&-1\end{array}\right]}$ ${\left[\begin{array}{ccc}2&2&0\\0&-i&0\end{array}\right]}$ ${\left[\begin{array}{ccc}i&-i&-i\\0&0&2\end{array}\right]} \}$

From vectors in set A choose basis $span(A)$

I'm not sure if it's good but I would try to type matrices to column like this: ${\left[\begin{array}{ccc}i&i&2&i\\i&i&2&-i\\i&-i&0&i\\i&-i&0&0\\0&-1&i&0\\1&-1&0&2\end{array}\right]}$ and reduce it and convert it to $4$ matrices at the end, is my idea ok ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly the right idea...but type the matrices as ROWS and then ROW-reduce (or you could column-reduce). You're starting with four matrices, so you expect to end up with no more than 4 independent rows.

Looking at it for 5 seconds, it looks to me as if the resulting basis will have either 3 or 4 matrices.

Comment: Ok it will looks like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=rref%7B%28i%2Ci%2Ci%2Ci%2C0%2C1%29%2C+%28i%2Ci%2C-i%2C-i%2C-1%2C-1%29%2C+%282%2C2%2C0%2C0%2C-i%2C0%29%2C+%28i%2C-i%2C-i%2C0%2C0%2C2%29%7D) so the answer is $4$ matrices with this coordinates ?

Comment: That's what I got (doing it by hand), yes.